# Creating a list in Python and inserting into Oracle table, and then able to retrieve the count ,but the values are not found in oracle table

Tags: python

Creating a list in python and inserting into oracle table , but no records found in oracle table.

1. Created a list in python.
2. Created a Oracle table using Python code.
3. Using executeMany inserted the list.
4. Run the count(*) query in python and obtained the number of rows and printed in python.

Output : Table has been created in Oracle using python code succesfully , but cannot find the records inserted using python

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@127.0.0.1/orcl')
cursor = con.cursor()
create_table = """CREATE TABLE python_modules ( module_name VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL, file_path VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL )"""
cursor.execute(create_table)
M = []
M.append(('Module1', 'c:/1'))
M.append(('Module2', 'c:/2'))
M.append(('Module3', 'c:3'))

cursor.prepare("INSERT INTO python_modules(module_name, file_path) VALUES (:1, :2)")
cursor.executemany(None,M)
con.commit

cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM python_modules")
print(cursor.fetchone() [0])
```

Executing below query "select  * from python_modules " should have the 3 records in Oracle SQL Developer tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your commit to `con.commit()`.